# Power BI USERELATIONSHIP Resulting in no data

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I currently have two relationship between my 'Activity Log' table and 'All Reports' table.

Active Relationship: 1 - Many on the [report_id] which is found in both tables. This relationship works as expected.

Inactive Relationship: Many - Many on the [workspace_report_id] which is also found in both tables.

**This workspace_report_id is a superset of the above report_id's, essentially if a report is found in the workspace it is the report_id but if it is a report found in an app, it produces the report_id of the original workspace report_id. This is so I can capture an data around reports being updated in the workspace.

I have two measure calculating the same thing, but one uses the userelationship function.

```
Active Relationship Views = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Activity Log'[activity_id]),
    FILTER('Activity Type','Activity Type'[Activity] = "viewReport")
)

Inactive Relationship Views = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Activity Log'[activity_id]),
    FILTER('Activity Type','Activity Type'[Activity] = "viewReport"),
    USERELATIONSHIP('All Reports'[workspace_report_id],'Activity Log'[workspace_report_id])
)
```

They both are producing the same result when they shouldn't. Here is the image of the table output. The Inactive Relationship Views should be bigger. It isn't using the userelationship function in the dax
[image]

Here is my model. [image]

*** For the picture I took out the activity table that is in my Dax measures. But there is a dimension table in my model called activity.
The active relationship again is on report_id, and the inactive relationship is on the workspace_report_id.

The interesting thing is, when I delete my original active relationship and activate my originally inactive relationship. The measure now calculates correctly.

That is what I have done here, these are now the correct results.[image]

So there is something with the userelationship function. It isn't turning on the inactive relationship and turning off the active relationship.

Comment: Using the Performance Analyzer in Power BI Desktop capture and share the DAX queries for those two visuals.  But why not just add Workspace as a table in your model if you want to see all the activity for a workspace.  Workspaces -> Apps -> Reports -> ActivityLog seems like the natural model here, and messing around with inactive relationsihps is unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft


// DAX Query
DEFINE
  VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
    TREATAS({"CAMID"}, 'Apps'[App])

  VAR __DS0Core = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL('All Reports'[Report], "IsGrandTotalRowTotal"),
      __DS0FilterTable,
      "Inactive_Relationship_Views", 'Activity Log'[Inactive Relationship Views],
      "Views", 'Activity Log'[Views]
    )

  VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
    TOPN(502, __DS0Core, [IsGrandTotalRowTotal], 0, 'All Reports'[Report], 1)

EVALUATE
  __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
  [IsGrandTotalRowTotal] DESC, 'All Reports'[Report]

Comment: I am unsure if you are familiar with the Power BI Activity Log and workspace tables and models. But I do actually have workspace in my model and the app table obviously. I can't have the workspace  and app table filter my activity log since they are already filtering my reports table. That would be ambiguous. 

What I am trying to do is create a measure that would allow me to see all the views or edits on a report in workspace, when I am looking at a report within an app. 

So if the report page is filtered to an app, I can use this userelationship function to see the workspace report info

Comment: I ran the performance analyzer again for the inactive relationship measure but in a card and got this --

// DAX Query
DEFINE VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
  TREATAS({"CAMID"}, 'Apps'[App])

EVALUATE
  SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    __DS0FilterTable,
    "Inactive_Relationship_Views", IGNORE('Activity Log'[Inactive Relationship Views])
  )

The "Ignore" is interesting but I don't know if that is the issue.

Comment: Regardless of the model though, I don't understand why the use relationship isn't working here.

Comment: In that case you want active relationships Workspace->Report->Activity, since not all reports are on the App.  Then you can simply filter or slice by the Workspace.

Comment: I do have that in my published model, I technicall have to workspace => app => reports => activity. They issue with the set up is. If someone has filtered the page to a certain app, I won't be able to see the edits, views, reportcreation, ect on those reports since those technically happen at the workspace report level. So for every report, i included the "workspace_report_id" so that I can also see those types of details. My end users want to see when the final edit was for example on a report even if they are looking at it from an app context.

Comment: When a report is published to an app, a new report id is created. That is what i use normally to connect to the activity log to get the app specifc views of that report. But in certain circumstances i need to link the original workspace report id, to capture these other details.

Comment: @Noahantoun, can you add a picture of model, when you cut the first link and activates the second with a pictures of link properties before and after? I mean it can be many reasons for your issue and it can be we will not find a sollution, but  as for me it's better to check as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you need to use crossfilter() to make filter direction both sides. Please test this, and let me know if It solves your problem.

```
Inactive_Relationship_Views =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Activity Log'[activity_id] ),
    FILTER ( 'Activity Type', 'Activity Type'[Activity] = "viewReport" ),
    CROSSFILTER ( 'All Reports'[workspace_report_id], 'Activity Log'[workspace_report_id], BOTH )
)
```

Comment: That didn't work sadly, i got the same outcome.